# prompt and execCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt, execcommand

if I comment the line 1 and uncomment the line 2, this code works. What is the problem with the prompt?

```
let parte = prompt("What is your name?"); //line 1
//let parte = "Batman"; // line 2
let documents = "bla bla bla";
let $dummy = $("<input>");

$dummy.attr("value",  parte+ " " + documents);
$("body").append($dummy);
$dummy.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
$dummy.remove();
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Does the prompt appear?

Comment: When is this code executed? `execCommand('copy')` must be called from a short lived user-generated event (e.g inside a click event)

Comment: Please specify what you mean by itnworking or not working.

Answer (score 0):

## `.execCommand()` Needs to be in an Event Handler

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for form controls but `.attr()` will work as well. In the demo the rest of your code will not work without an event handler. Refer to [*Using `.execCommand();`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Using_execCommand()).

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
let parte = prompt("What is your name?");
let documents = "bla bla bla";
let $dummy = $("<input>");

// Use .val() for input values is better either one will work.
$dummy.val(parte + " " + documents);
//$dummy.attr("value", parte+ " " + documents);
$("body").append($dummy);

// You need to make an event handler
function copy() {
  $dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $dummy.remove();
}
$('.copy').on('click', copy);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class='copy'>Copy</button>

<fieldset class='edit' contenteditable>
  Paste Here
</fieldset>
```

Comment: jQuery.fn.select is a default method and as long as the input has not been appended to the doc, `attr()` should also work. https://jsfiddle.net/4oLn9k5p/

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way to make this code work without having to click the button.

Comment: You click click anything you register an event on as long as `execCommand()` is inside an event handler. If you want to programmatically accomplish the task then `execCommand()` isn't the right kind of method to use since it requires user interaction.